# Nested element in custom control is missing in the Visual Tree

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I do have two problems regarding custom controls:

I created a custom UserControl

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
public static DependencyProperty ControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Control", typeof(UIElement), typeof(MyControl ), null);

 public UIElement Control
        {
            get { return GetValue(ControlProperty) as UIElement; }
            set { SetValue(ControlProperty,value); }
        }
}
```

Now I want to embed any "regular" control into my control using XAML

```
<Grid>
<own:MyControl>
<own:MyControl.Control>
<TextBox x:Name="txtTest" />
</own:MyControl.Control>
</own:MyControl>  
</Grid>
```

1) When trying to access the TextBox by its name in code-behind I just can't because it is null. What might the problem be? If I would place the same TextBox just inside the Grid the name would resolve to the instance as it should.

2) I can't find my class using the VisualTreeHelper. The *GetChild* method just pretends my control isn't there. Why does this happen?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VisualTreeHelper isn't "pretending" at all.  The value of the `MyControl.Control` property is **not** in the Visual Tree.  Just being present in the Xaml does not mean it will be added to the visual tree.

Only when the control is added as a child of UI Element that is already in the Visual Tree such as a Panel, a ContentControl or a Border will it also become part of the visual tree.

You could do this:-

```
<Grid>
  <own:MyControl x:Name="myControl">
    <own:MyControl.Control>
      <TextBox x:Name="txtTest" />
    </own:MyControl.Control>
  </own:MyControl>  
</Grid>
```

In code-behind:-

```
txtTest = myControl.Control as TextBox;
```

Probably isn't what you are trying to do, so what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: No, the Control is wrapper that changes few properties and styles depending on the context. It needs to be included in existing XAML code and therefore the controls need to be available from code-behind as they were before - just by their name. How do I change my control in a way it acts as a Panel?

Comment: @Muffel: As a Panel, in that you want to control the measuring and arranging of multiple controls or are you really only wanting to wrap a single child control (bear in mind that control could itself be Grid etc containing other controls)?

Comment: I do have two properties, but to no complicate this consider one property of type IEnumerable<UIElement>, quite similar to the *Children* property of the *Panel* class. The elements are internally added to a regular *Grid*. After being added to the grid some DependencyProperty's are set on each control. What really is important to me is that I can include this into existing XAML and access each containing control just by its name. Is there any (easy) way to realize this?